# How to implement BehaviorSubject + retrofit api call

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm a newbie in RxJava.

I'm use retrofit for api calls api.java:

```
@GET("someurl")
Observable<Profile> getProfile();
```

I want to implement some service with a method, that return `Observable<Profile>` and:

1) if somebody first subscribes to observable, then at the start called API request and the result (profile) will available at the subscriber.

2) If somebody else subscribes to observable, then subscriber get already cached data (from the first subscriber) without API call. Same for 3rd, 4th subscribers...

3) Some new subscriber wants to get "last" data over API call. In this case, will be called API request and all subscribers get last data.

My solution MyService.java:

```
private final BehaviorSubject<Profile> profile = BehaviorSubject.create();

public BehaviorSubject<Profile> subscribe(boolean useCache) {
        if (!useCache || !profile.hasValue()) {
            api.getProfile().subscribe(new Consumer<Profile>() {

                @Override
                public void accept(UserProfile result) throws Exception {
                    profile.onNext(result);
                }
            });
        }

        return profile;
    }
```

But this solution seems very cumbrous. Also, there is no unsubscription after API call.

Answer (score 0):

Have your subject subscribe to you actual API observable, then other subscribes subscribe to the Subject instead.

```
Api api = getRetrofitApiInterfaceIpml();
BehaviorSubject<Profile> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
Observable<Profile> profileObservable = api.getProfile();
profileObservable.subscribe(subject);
```

Then expose the Subject as observable to be subscribed to.

Comment: Hm, I see in http logs, that api called, but no data available if subscribed to subject.